# jdk 17 with spring-boot-starter-cache throwing Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager' defined in class path resource

Tags: java-17

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]

Jdk version upgraded to 17 from 11

I have upgraded the version of java from 11 to 17 due to some other dependency version upgrade internally in the project. Which is now causing an issue with the spring-boot-starter-cache. How can I make sure that it is compatible with jdk17 or not